# Facebook php sdk Login issue

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, authentication

This is the [link](http://facebook.ebis-servicii.ro/mytest/) where I develop.  I'm wondering why this script is working only for me ? I have another facebook user and when i press the login link it does not redirect me properly. WHY ???

```
<?php 

    require '../src/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXXXXXX',
      'cookie' => true
    ));
?>
<?php
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array ( 
                    //'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_groups,user_about_me,user_interests,friends_groups,friends_interests,friends_about_me',
                    'scope' => 'email',
                    'redirect_uri' => 'http://facebook.ebis-servicii.ro/mytest/test.php'
            ));

    echo '<a href = "'.$loginUrl.'">Login Here </a> ';
?>
```

this is my set and reviews: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure the app is not in sandbox mode or the second user is added at least as a tester. This bit me a few times.

Comment: Probably because your app is still in development mode, so only people that have a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) can use it – you have to set it “live” before other users can.

Comment: and how do i set it live ? is there a tutorial or smth ?

Comment: There's a toggle button on top of the app's "status & review" tab on the developers portal.

Comment: Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?  <== I set this to yes, but with no result

Comment: "i have another facebook user" - multi accounts are not allowed on facebook. just saying.

Comment: @luschn did you get the data of yours ?

Comment: what data? i only told you that multi accounting is not allowed, that is all.

Comment: you said that this application, cannot be used by other users ?

Comment: @luschn How can i make my application to work for other users ?

Comment: i did not say any of that, i only said that you are not allowed to have more than one user on facebook. "does not redirect properly" is not enough information to help you in a serious way.

Comment: @luschn what kind of information can I provide you in order to help me ?

Comment: well, "it does not work" is not a proper error description, obviously. i suggest using FB.login for authorization, not the PHP SDK (especially when you are using an old version of it). much better for usability and a lot easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your app is still in development mode. That means your app isn't available to people who aren't administrators, developers or testers (as set in "Roles" within the app's settings).

[image]

So it appears as if the app just does not exist (no redirect etc.).

To set your app live, go to "Status & Review" and you'll see the option.

Comment: There may be other settings blocking your login:
Settings -> Advanced -> Security -> "Client OAuth Login" set to No?
You could also try to add your redirect URL to the app's Domains (Settings -> Basics).

Comment: please check my post again, and see my settings. maybe im doing smth wrong

Comment: finnally i manage to make a login, but now im not getting informations about other users. What am i missing at the setting zone? the userid is 0